# In logic, what's the difference between not being a Tautology and being a Contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given this statement: `The negation of a contradiction is a tautology.`

Let T(x) mean that x is a tautology and C(x) mean that x is a contradiction.

My response is $\forall$x(C(x)$\rightarrow$ $\neg$ T(x)), however, in the textbook says the correct answer is  $\forall$x(C(x)$\rightarrow$ T( $\neg$x)).

I was wondering why is my answer not the correct case? And what is the difference between $\neg$ T(x) and T( $\neg$x)?

Thanks.

Comment: Before we can say anything about what the right answer is maybe you should tell us what the **question** is...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The question is to express the given statement using quantifiers. And that statement is the very first sentence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula $X$ is a Contradiction when it is **always** FALSE [example: $p \land \lnot p$].

A formula $X$ is a Tautology when it is **always** TRUE [example: $p \lor \lnot p$].

If $X$ is a Contradiction, then $\lnot X$ is a Tautology, and vice-versa [$\lnot (p \land \lnot p) \equiv (\lnot p \lor p)$, by De Morgan].

But a formula that is **not** a Tautology is a formula that is **sometime** FALSE, like e.g. $p \lor q$, and this does not mean that it is **always** FALSE.

*Conclusion*: $¬ \text {Taut}(X)$ and $\text {Taut}( ¬X)$ are not the same.